# If two armies arriving on the same day, which one is attacking/defending?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

During a war, I moved my troop on a captured province (of mine) near the enemy territory. My troop met an enemy troop and they arrived the same day on the province.

**Which one is attacking and defending in this case ?**

Knowing this may change  battles considering offensive and defensive states have their respective and different bonus.

Comment: I believe that both general's movement stat will be compared, and the one with the higher stat will be defending. But I can't validate this theory for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes through the country in order by their tag, following this list (https://eu4.paradoxwikis.com/Countries)

EG. If France and England are fighting each other and their two armies will both arrive on the 19th of may, England will be defending and France will be attacking because England (43) will arrive at the province first and France (106) will arrive second.

Note that Rebels Pirates and Natives are first, and the Roman Empire and special countries are last.

Answer (score 1):

If they both arrived at the same time, the defending party goes to whoever is controlling the province at the time, and that would be you correct?

Happy to help :)

Comment: Where did you take the information? What if the battle is on a neutral province (not in the war)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how far a an armies hold on the province is if your army has most land mass of the province covered or controlled by the army then you will be the defender unless you are the smaller land holder marching onto the enemies land then you are attacker.

Comment: Where did you learn this?

Comment: Instead of asking where did they learn this (probably through playing game if you ask me), you would rather answer that is correct or not. :-D I have exactly same situation right now and I would like to be sure.

Comment: @Drachenfels you're right, but the situation didn't happen again since.